# ReactJS clear input value (can not use submit) after button click

Tags: reactjs

I have an app, let's call it Stopwatch so you know how it is working.

First, it have second meter which you can pause by pressing stop (stop button appears when pressing start), then you are able to start it again from the paused place or reset and start over.

If i use submit method in the form for saving time value and title, it works fine, but it reset time counter also and make stupid "white flash" after submitting.  So i cant use it.

**Problem of the case:** I made button outside of the form, and it works almost fine. I want clear input with that button also. I tried these inside of the button function, but not working:

`document.getElementById("title-value").reset();`

`document.getElementById("title-value").value = '';`

Here is my code (and picture of app below):

```
import React from 'react';

class StopwatchHistory extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      history: [],
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  handleChange(event) {    this.setState({value: event.target.value});  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setHistoryState();
  }


  setHistoryState = () => {
    if (localStorage.times) {
      this.setState({ history: localStorage.times.split('|') });
    } else {
      this.setState({ history: [] });
    }
  };



  saveToLocalStorage = () => {

    let titletieto = `${this.state.value}`; // form input value

    // printing title and time to appearing list
    if (localStorage.times) {
      localStorage.times =
        `${titletieto} ${this.props.formatTime(
          this.props.currentTimeMin
        )}:${this.props.formatTime(
          this.props.currentTimeSec
        )}:${this.props.formatTime(this.props.currentTimeMs, 'ms')}|` +
        localStorage.times;
    } else {
      localStorage.times = `${titletieto} ${this.props.formatTime(
        this.props.currentTimeMin
      )}:${this.props.formatTime(
        this.props.currentTimeSec
      )}:${this.props.formatTime(this.props.currentTimeMs, 'ms')}|`;
    }
  };


  saveTime = () => {
    if (typeof Storage !== 'undefined') {
      this.saveToLocalStorage();
    } else {
      console.error('local storage not supported');
    }
    this.setHistoryState();
  };

  // Remove times from Local Storage
  resetHistory = () => { 
    if (localStorage.times) {
      localStorage.removeItem('times');
    }
    this.setHistoryState();
  };

 



  render() {
    return (
      <div className={'stopwatch__history'}>
        <div className="container">
          <form id="title-value" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />        </label>
          </form>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.saveTime}>SAVE TIME</button>
        <button onClick={this.resetHistory}>RESET HISTORY</button>
        
        <h3>History</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.state.history.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
        
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default StopwatchHistory;
```

[image: Image of an app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is controlled input. You have value set to be value={this.state.value} and handle change function is:

```
handleChange(event) {    this.setState({value: event.target.value});  }
```

so if you want to reset this input, your reset function would simply set that state.value to be an empty string.

```
reset = () => { 
  this.setState({value: ""});
};
```

If your input would be uncontrolled (so value and onChange would not be provided) you could change it by accessing it through Ref. (see React.createRef).

Comment: My man, that's working completely nice. Thanks!